# How to pass value from functional child component to class parent component and save value to state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have a parent class component that has a functional child table component. When a user selects a row in the table component, I am attempting to capture the row data (the data is an object), return it to the parent component, and then save it to the state. I am currently running into the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

I've referenced this Stack question, but this does not save the value from the child component to the state in the parent component: [How to pass value from a child functional component to parent class component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60487182/how-to-pass-value-from-a-child-functional-component-to-parent-class-component)

**Question**: How can I save the value to the state?

Parent class component

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedRows: []
        };
    }

    setSelectedDataTableRow(selectedRow) {
        console.log('setSelectedDataTableRow triggered!', selectedRow);
        this.setState({selectedRows: selectedRow}) //this is causing the error
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <ChildComponent 
                     otherProps={otherProps} 
                     setSelectedDataTableRow={this.setSelectedDataTableRow} 
                />
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Child functional component

```
const ChildComponent = ({ otherProps, setSelectedDataTableRow }) => {
    const ROWS_PER_PAGE = 5;
    const captureRowData = (data) => {
        setSelectedDataTableRow(data)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <DataGrid
                //other attributes
                onRowSelected={(e) => captureRowData(e.data)}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: `setSelectedDataTableRow={this.setSelectedDataTableRow}` => `setSelectedDataTableRow={this.setSelectedDataTableRow.bind(this)}`

Comment: Thanks, Dave. That did the trick!!

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution provided by Dave in the comments did the trick.
Posting it here as the answer:

```
setSelectedDataTableRow={this.setSelectedDataTableRow}
```

updated to

```
setSelectedDataTableRow={this.setSelectedDataTableRow.bind(this)}
```